What does "rising at the best part of two kilometers a minute." mean?
This is a part of the book "Brave New World" by Aldous Huxley in which a pilot and a passenger are in a helicopter and being the flight. They ascend vertically.
"The speedometer showed that they were rising at the best part of two kilometers a minute. London diminished beneath them."
the best part of
phrase of best
most of.
"the tedious ceremony took the best part of a day"
Based on the definition I provided, if the sentence was "The speedometer showed they were rising for the best part of the ascent at two kilometers a minute." I would have no difficulty understanding it. Is this the sense of the sentence? Or maybe the sentence means that they were "rising for most of the 2 kilometers (e.g. 1,8 km) which took them a minute" but in this case- I think- the sentence should be "...they were rising for the best part of two kilometers" and not "...they were rising at the best part of two kilometers".

If they rose at that speed, they'd need oxygen masks in around 90 seconds, unless the helicopter was pressurised.

@MichaelHarvey The altitude after 90 seconds would be only 3,000 metres. I have been higher than that in mountains, without oxygen. Passenger airliners are required to activate emergency oxygen masks if depressurisation occurs at above 14,000 feet (4,267 metres).

@JavaLatte - thanks. I thought it was 10,000 feet for some reason, perhaps that Acute Mountain Sickness (AMS) is common at high altitudes and at elevations over 10,000 feet (3,048 metres), 75% of people will have mild symptoms.

The phrase describes their speed of ascent. The best (or 'better' [biggest]) part of some quantity means nearly that quantity or a little less than that quantity. The best part of 2 km a/per minute means nearly 2 km a/per minute. The best part of a million dollars means nearly a million dollars. My car crash cost me the best part of $1000.

The best/better part of
idiom
most of:
I spent the better part of a day cleaning that kitchen!

The Best/Better part of (Cambridge Dictionary)

Yes, the helicopter was not "rising for the best part of the ascent," but its speed was as much as 2km/minute.

Is "the best part of {any quantity}" a widely used construction in BrE? I've often heard "the better part of {some duration}" as in I stayed there for the better part of the summer but I haven't ever heard the "better|best part of {a speed}"

@TimR - it is reasonably common. Shorty did not move a muscle. He had been making the best part of fifty miles an hour. (Boy's comic, 1930) It [a van] couldn't have been much more than ten feet off the rear wheel of the Norton, and at the best part of fifty miles an hour in the dark, that was a great deal too close for comfort. (Novel, 2011) she herself was invisible and inaudible, and with the wind well back on her quarter making the best part of fifty miles an hour. (Novel, 2003) All UK examples.

OP has asked the interpretation of:

The speedometer showed that they were rising at the best part of two kilometers a minute. London diminished beneath them.

It means that the speed of ascent was nearly two kms a minute.
Ref. Collins dictionary

If you say that something happened for the best part or the better part of a period of time, you mean that it happened for most of that time. He had been in Israel for the best part of twenty-four hours

Ref. Merriam Webster dictionary

more than half of (something) : most of (something) It took us the better part of a week to finish the job. We've been waiting for the best part of an hour.

Aldous Huxley used the term "the best part of two kilometers per minute". It shows that the the speed wasn't precise or constant.
Typically, a speedometer shows speed in units of distance per hour (e.g., miles per hour or kilometers per hour), not distance per minute (e.g., kilometers per minute).
Aldous Huxley's depiction of helicopters in Brave New World (1932) was influenced by his research on emerging technologies of the time.
Given the early stage of helicopter development in the 1930s, it's plausible that Huxley's understanding of their capabilities and limitations led him to describe the speedometer needle as unsteady.

It means that when they looked at the speedometer, it showed a reading a little less than 2,000 metres per minute. It is abundantly clear that Huxley had never been in a helicopter. Neither had many other people in 1932.

You have the wrong idea when you write 'most of the time'. The instrument reading took place once.

How do you work out that it means "approximately two kms a minute"? Both of the definitions indicate that it means "less than two kms per minute".

@JavaLatte I have given the explanation in my post. Because speed is not constant the author used the term. It's clearly explained. Many times you have to take the meaning by the context.

@JavaLatte approximately means roughly and not exact amount.

@JamesMathai, however the best part of is not the same as approximately. It will by definition be a lesser amount. Think almost. The best part of 2 kilometres can be 1.6 km or 1.9km, but not 2.1 km.

@PeterKirkpatrick If the reading was taken only once, why didn't the author put a precise figure. By using this phrase, the author is able to convey a sense of speed and momentum without getting bogged down in precise details. It's a great example of how language can be used to create a vivid and immersive narrative.

I agree generally with what you're saying about the style of the narrative. But a vivid style of writing doesn't mean that we can make the words say anything. He could have written almost 2 km a minute. Or he could have written about 2 km a minute. We would not use "vivid and immersive language" to argue that almost and about are therefore synonyms. The fact is that the best part of means almost, not about.

James, Huxley wrote the book in 1931; the first production helicopter came ten years later. He was imagining what a ride in a helicopter might be like. He talked of ascending vertically at (nearly) 2,000 metres per minute (which would be amazing even today, when helicopters usually manage one-third to half of that rate; they 'make lousy elevators'). Furthermore, he says the 'speedometer' showed they were climbing at nearly 2 km/min. My impression is that Huxley imagined a dial graduated in km/min, with a pointer nearly at the 2 mark at the moment when the narrator looked.

@JamesMathai I know what approximately means and I know what "the best part of" means, and the meanings are not the same- whatever the context. "less than" is fundamentally different to "roughly". The purpose of the ELL site is to explain to users exactly what a word or expression means: your answer is incorrect.

@MichaelHarvey In July 1901, the maiden flight of Hermann Ganswindt's helicopter took place in Berlin-Schöneberg; this was probably the first heavier-than-air motor-driven flight carrying humans. A movie covering the event was taken by Max Skladanowsky, but it remains lost. If the speedometer reading happened only once why isn't it precise?

James, have you ever been in an older car with an analog speedometer? You are a passenger and further away from the speedo than the the driver, you can see the pointer and the numbers around the edge - 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 (etc). The pointer is a bit below 40. It would be reasonable to say you are travelling at 'the best part of 40 mph/kph'. It would be mad to expect someone in a book to say the speed was 38.75.

By 1930, the year before the book was written, the helicopter records were altitude (18 m or 59 ft), duration (8 minutes 45 seconds) and distance flown (1,078 m or 3,540 ft).
